i am getting an error when passing useState setter function as a callback
The issue I am getting is that I get Uncaught TypeError: param2 is not a function when I pass a setter function as an argument.
I am building a react calculator app. I have created a seperate file called constants.jsx whick contains data about all the buttons that I want on the calculator app. it looks somethiing like this:
export const mathSymbols = [
    {
        symbol: 'AC',
        callback: (param) => param(''), // this is the callback where the console throws an error
        type: 'clear',
        bg: 'bg-rose-100'
    }
]

I want to pass setEvalData which is a useState setter function const [evalData, setEvalData] = useState('') and pass it as an argument in the callback function.
Everything is working fine but I am getting error in the console.
Uncaught TypeError: param2 is not a function
    at Object.callback (constants.jsx:5:37)
    at handleDataInput (Key.jsx:13:13)
    at onClick (Key.jsx:20:28)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom_client.js?v=aa76ee9e:3672:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom_client.js?v=aa76ee9e:3697:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom_client.js?v=aa76ee9e:3731:39)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom_client.js?v=aa76ee9e:3734:33)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom_client.js?v=aa76ee9e:7012:11)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom_client.js?v=aa76ee9e:7032:15)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom_client.js?v=aa76ee9e:7041:13)

// constants.jsx

// This is my file that contains data about the buttons

export const mathSymbols = [
    {
        symbol: 'AC',
        callback: (param) => param(''), // this is the callback where the console throws an error
        type: 'clear',
        bg: 'bg-rose-100'
    },
    {
        symbol: '()',
        callback: (bool = true) => bool ? ')' : '(', // this works fine
        type: 'math',
        bg: 'bg-blue-200'

    },
    {
        symbol: '%',
        value: '%',
        type: 'math',
        bg: 'bg-blue-200'

    },
    {
        symbol: '\u00F7',
        value: '/',
        type: 'math',
        bg: 'bg-blue-200'

    },
    {
        symbol: '\u2A2F',
        value: '*',
        type: 'math',
        bg: 'bg-blue-200'
    },
    {
        symbol: '-',
        value: '-',
        type: 'math',
        bg: 'bg-blue-200'

    },
    {
        symbol: '+',
        value: '+',
        type: 'math',
        bg: 'bg-blue-200'
    },
    {
        symbol: '=',
        callback: (param) => param(previousData => eval(previousData)),  // this is the callback where the console throws an error
        type: 'math',
        bg: 'bg-blue-300'
    }
]

export const numbers = [
    {
        symbol: '9',
        value: 9,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '8',
        value: 8,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '7',
        value: 7,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '6',
        value: 6,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '5',
        value: 5,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '4',
        value: 4,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '3',
        value: 3,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '2',
        value: 2,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '1',
        value: 1,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '0',
        value: 0,
        type: 'number',
    },
    {
        symbol: '.',
        value: '.',
        type: 'dot',
    },
    {
        symbol: '',
        callback: 'del',
        type: 'del',
    },
]


// Keys.jsx

// this is my calculator button component
export default function Key({ data, setEvalData, leftBracketExist, setLeftBracketExist }) {
  
  function handleDataInput(k) {
// if data does not have a callback property then input previous data in useState + the value from the  
// clicked button
    if(!data?.callback) {
      setEvalData(previousData => previousData + k)
      return
    }

// if callback exists in data then I am passing setEvalData which is a useState setter function to 
// callback    
    if(data?.callback) {
      data.callback(setEvalData)
    }

// ignore this
    if(data.callback() === '(' || data.callback() === ')') {
      setEvalData(previousData => previousData + data.callback(leftBracketExist))
      setLeftBracketExist(!leftBracketExist)
    }

  }
  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleDataInput(data.value)} className={'prevent-select w-full sm:max-w-[90%] aspect-square rounded-[50%] text-xs md:text-sm flex items-center justify-center ' + (data?.bg || ' bg-blue-100')}>
      {data.symbol}
    </button>
  )
}


// KeyPad.jsx

// This is the calculator's keypad containing all the buttons


// here I am importing data from constants.jsx
import { mathSymbols, numbers } from "../utils/constants"


import { Key } from "."
import { useState } from "react"

export default function KeyPad({ setEvalData }) {
  const [leftBracketExist, setLeftBracketExist] = useState(false)
  return (
    <section className='key-pad-grid w-full px-4 py-4'>
      <div className="grid w-full gap-1  grid-cols-3">
        {mathSymbols.slice(0, 3).map((symbol, i) => (
          <Key data={symbol} key={i} setEvalData={setEvalData} leftBracketExist={leftBracketExist} setLeftBracketExist={setLeftBracketExist}/>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="grid w-full gap-1 grid-cols-1 ml-1">
        {mathSymbols.slice(3).map((symbol, i) => (
          <Key data={symbol} key={i} setEvalData={setEvalData}/>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="grid w-full gap-1  grid-cols-3">
        {numbers.map((number, i) => (
          <Key data={number} key={i} setEvalData={setEvalData}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}



I guess the reason here is your if:
if (data.callback() === '(' || data.callback() === ')')

Here you call callback function knowing that callback exists, but you pass nothing (read as undefined) to it. So, your param in callback is now undefined. Calling param() if param is undefined causes the error param2 is not a function.
